# Bash Array Variable

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I am trying to write a script to execute a couple of different java/r programs but I am having an issue with using a value from an array in bash. 
Here is my example:

```
INPUTS[0]=$1 #file
INPUTS[1]=$2 #file
INPUTS[2]=$3 #file
INPUTS[3]=$4 #file
TARGET=$5 #file
OUTPUTS[0]=$6 #file
OUTPUTS[1]=$7 #file
OUTPUTS[2]=$8 #file
OUTPUTS[3]=$9 #file
TYPE=$10 #file
PANEL=$11 #String

for ((X=0;X<${#INPUTS[@]};X++));do #for every file in this array
   CURRENT="${INPUTS[X]}" #look at current in file
   CURRENTOUT="${OUTPUTS[X]}" #and current out file
   #this is working just fine. I put in a file myfile.txt and it makes a new file **results.txt**
   java -jar javathing.jar INPUT=$CURRENT TARG=$TARGET OUTPUT=$CURRENTOUT IS=True #run this
   #This is throwing an error because it can't find **results.txt0**
   java -jar morejava.jar -i $CURRENTOUT -o $TYPE #then this
done
Rscript rthing.R $TYPE $PANEL #finally
```

So my first java outputs the correct file with a correct file name- results.txt

But when my second java program goes to look for it, it looks for the incorrect name. It looks  for results.txt0

I am using the same variable for each one, but it doesn't seem to have the same effect. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: For starters, `//` isn't a Bash comment character.

Comment: @CodeGnome I don't have those in my actual code. I was commenting just for the sake of this post. Does Stackoverflow have a comment character? As it seems there are at least 2 nitpickers I will change it.

Comment: Use the comment character of the language you're writing. `#` for bash

Comment: There's no way the variable `CURRENTOUT` can change between those two statements.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you can set the arrays more concisely with `INPUT=( "${@:1:4}" )` and `OUTPUT=( "${@:6:4}" )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix these lines:

```
TYPE=$10 #file
PANEL=$11 #String
```

They should be:

```
TYPE=${10} #file
PANEL=${11} #String
```

From the `bash` man page:

> When a positional parameter consisting of more than a single digit is expanded, it must be enclosed  in  braces  (see  EXPANSION below).

What you wrote was interpreted as:

```
TYPE=${1}0
PANEL=${1}1
```

Comment: Why would I do this for these two variables, but none of the others?

Comment: Because the other positional parameters only have 1 digit.

Comment: You can use the braces for the others if you like, you just don't _need_ to.